# Azure Cognitive Search: How to use AddSearchClient<TBuilder,TConfiguration>(TBuilder, TConfiguration)

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

There is an extension method located in `Microsoft.Extensions.Azure` namespace for ease registering clients. It works nicely.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(b =>
{
    b.AddSearchClient(
        new Uri("https://" + searchServiceConfiguration.Host),
        searchServiceConfiguration.IndexName,
        new AzureKeyCredential(searchServiceConfiguration.QueryApiKey));
    b.AddSearchIndexClient(new Uri("https://" + searchServiceConfiguration.Host), new AzureKeyCredential(searchServiceConfiguration.AdminApiKey));
});
```

But there is an overload, which takes configuration object: `AddSearchClient<TBuilder,TConfiguration>(TBuilder, TConfiguration)`.

I need to configure `SearchClientOptions` like this

```
private readonly SearchClientOptions _options = new()
{
Serializer = new JsonObjectSerializer(
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    })
};
```

I'm wondering if I can configure a client with these options (and other props: key, uri, index name) when registering SearchClient. So far, no luck with creating required configuration object. Maybe somebody have an idea how to use mentioned overload and if this allow to pass options?

I tried to find out how TConfiguration object should look like, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can configure the `SearchClientOptions`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddSearchClient(new Uri("http://my.search.com"), "indexName", new AzureKeyCredential("ApiKey"))
        .ConfigureOptions((options) =>
        {
            options.Serializer = new JsonObjectSerializer(
                    new JsonSerializerOptions
                    {
                        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
                    });

            options.Retry.MaxRetries = 10;
        });
    });
}
```

For reference, here is the [Microsoft.Extensions.Azure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/README.md#register-clients) documentation, where you can find how to use `AddAzureClients` and configure options.